# C# referencing FileNet IDM objects

Tags: c#, vb.net, adodb

I have been given a task to convert VB.Net code to c#. I used the code converter. The code is for opening IBM File net IDM objects. Knew nothing about them until now.
There are 2 issue areas while converting. 
I searched through, and I could not find IDM object docs. What works in VB.Net code, shows me error in c#.

**1.**

```
Dim objDoc As IDMObjects.Document
objDoc = oLib.CreateObject(idmObjectType.idmObjTypeDocument, "office_Docs")`
```

in c# , we get a error :

```
IDMObjects.Document ObjDoc = new IDMObjects.Document();
ObjDoc = oLib.CreateObject(idmObjectType.idmObjTypeDocument, "office_Docs");
```

The Error Says:

> Cannot implicitly convert IDMObjects.genericobjects to IDMobjects.Document

**2.**

The Vb.NET code is trying to open

```
objCommand.CommandType = ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdText
objCommand.Properties("SupportsObjSet").Value = True
objCommand.CommandText = "select DOCNu from filenet where blah blah ...."
objRS = objCommand.Execute(, , ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdText)
```

It throws Error in c# :

> Argument missing in the second parameter.

I want to pass null in the second argument.

```
objRS = objCommand.Execute(null, ,ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdText);
```

Comment: I would suggest to always set in your vb.net projects Option Strict ON.

Comment: The error is quite clear - you're missing an argument in the method. Whether that method can be re-coded to not need it is something you're going to have to figure out on your own. You probably need to sharpen up your c# coding skills if you want to take on this project.

Comment: I found this limk helpful in casting the object:http://computer-programming-forum.com/4-csharp/339ea63d6ffdb19f.htm